# Converting double for loops from C to Mips and Addition in Arrays

Tags: arrays, assembly, dynamic, mips

I am working on a question about the course computer architecture in which I should convert some C code to Mips.

```
 int A[52], B[52];
    2 for (j = 1; j < 52 ; j++)
    3 for (i = j; i < 52; i++) {
    4 B[i] = B[i-1] + A[j] ;
    5 }
```

My translation to this is following.I think addi equals li but I dont know the real meaning of li so I used addi which lets me add a constant.Assume Array A is saved in $s0 and B is in S$1

```
   addi $t1, $0,  1   //setting j to 1
          addi   $t2 , $t1 , 0  //setting i (which is always equal to j) 
        addi     $t6, $t1 , -1  //this will be used for writing B[i-1]
            addi $t3,  $0, 50  //making a temp value 50 to end the loop.
        Loop:
        beq       $t3, $t1,end     //when j becomes 50 end the loop.
            beq  $t3, $t2,end     //when i becomes 50 end the loop.
        lw    $t4 , $s0          //loading A 
        lw  $t5, $s1              //loading B
         add 4$t1($t5),  4$t6($St5),4$t2($t4) //This is the part I think I am doing it //wrong.I want to write 4($t5)for first element 8 for second an so on but I dont //know how to do it.Is this a legit way?

sv  $t5, $s1               //storing B
addi   $t1, $t1, 1         //increment j by one.
addi   $t2,$t2,1          //increment i by one 
j            loop:
end
```

My questions is the following. Are there any universe I can add arrays like this and if not how can I.Also I can not check my answer since the book has no solution for this.The way I am doing the other operations are correct?

Answer (score 0):

I will post an answer since I think I solved the problem and this can be helpful if someone will have same problem with me.

```
loop
lw $t4 ,4($s1)  //First element
lw $t5, 0($s0)   //Zeroth element
add $t6, $tf $t4  
sw $t6, 4($s1)   //store
addi $s0 $s0  4  //Increment by 1
addi $s1 $s1 4 //Increment by 1
```